# I want to to use the replace function to scan a json object and then replace the matched word with a string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Json object in my javascript
I want to replace all Instances of 'hi' with 'hello'. 
This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var res1 = /hi/gi;
    var str = [{"hi":"new","hi":"sun","hi":"hi"}]; 
    var res = str.replace(res1, "hello");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Edit:

```
function myFunction() {
    var res1 = /hi/gi;
    var str = {"hi":[{"men":"hi","hi":"sun","hi":"hi"}]}; 
    var mouse = JSON.stringify(str);
    var res = mouse.replace(res1, "hello");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

after using this function it is only printing {"hello":[{"men":"hello","hello":"hello"}]} .. any reasons why it is not printing "hello":"sun ?

Comment: There is an error in your code when you run it. `str` is not a string, it is an array. Array's don't have the `.replace()` method.

Comment: you need to transform str into String before replace. to transform your object you can use [json stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/stringify)

Comment: @RayLloy could you please tell more as I am very new to JS and JSON.

Comment: @RayLloy i've made some changes. please see

Comment: In a jsonObject the key must be unique. In your jsonObject, you use the "hi" for many values. ex: `{"hi" : [{"hi1":"new","hi2":"sun","hi":"hi"}]}`

Answer (score 1):

This is not JSON object, this is just a Javascript object. JSON do has the smae syntax but don't mix them.

Furthermore by creating that object like this here is what you create :

1. [] -> str is an array
2. [{}] -> str is an array and his first value is an object
3. "hi":"new","hi":"sun","hi":"hi"} -> key value of the object

in the end : str[0].hi will have the value "hi" or "new" (don't know which one will be ignored). str[0].sun will have the value "hi".

I don't see why you would want to rename the key of your object. If you want to replace all value :

```
for(key in str[0]){
   str[key] = str[key].replace(res1, "hello");
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to be an array. I want to create a JSON object which should be scanned and then the matched value should be replaced. This is a little confusing to me

Comment: You don't understand what you're saying by "JSON object". A JSON object is a data format which is written the same as it is in javascript when you want to create objects/array. Every layer of object is composed of key and value. If there is definitively an interest to rewrite value, there is none to rename key. And having two times the same key just doesn't work, one will be skipped when data will be deserialized. What are you really trying to do ? Why do you need this ?

Comment: I am trying to replace every instance of word 'hi' in my json object with the world 'hello', even if it is repeating. Be it the key name 'hi' or the value 'hi'. It should just be replaced by 'hello'.